# Subselect in pgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to do a subselect in pgsql aka postgresql and the example I found doesn't work:

```
SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM table);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Is there an error message or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just needed to add an AS for the subselect, like so:

```
SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM table) AS aliasname;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table2);
```

I don't understand what your non-working subquery is attempting to do, it seems like you could just say `SELECT id FROM table` because presently its not valid SQL92 syntax.

Comment: My question was an overly simplified example